# no content from Wikipedia API search

Tags: api, search, wikipedia

Good morning

I am using the following API search, which used to return title, content and link of a Wikipedia entry:

`https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=alessandro%20leogrande&format=json&utf8=1`

Just recently I noticed that it is always returning an empty content part (`[""]`):

`["alessandro leogrande",["Alessandro Leogrande"],[""],["https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alessandro_Leogrande"]]`

Can you please give me any insight?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a problem with the OpenSearch API itself:
https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api/2019-December/004188.html